# Как залить часть svg, чтоб получилось что-то на подобее прогреса, красный поверх текущего серого?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<svg  viewBox="0 0 120 90" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.03805 90C2.78105 80.894 0.00902199 70.567 2.1988e-05 60.052C-0.00897801 49.538 2.74504 39.206 7.98604 30.091C13.228 20.976 20.772 13.398 29.864 8.11698C38.956 2.83598 49.276 0.0369857 59.791 -1.43436e-05C70.305 -0.0360143 80.645 2.69098 89.773 7.90798C98.902 13.126 106.499 20.651 111.804 29.729C117.109 38.807 119.935 49.12 119.999 59.634C120.063 70.148 117.363 80.495 112.169 89.637L91.302 77.782C94.418 72.297 96.038 66.089 95.999 59.78C95.961 53.472 94.265 47.284 91.082 41.837C87.9 36.39 83.341 31.875 77.864 28.745C72.387 25.614 66.183 23.978 59.875 24C53.566 24.022 47.374 25.702 41.919 28.87C36.463 32.039 31.937 36.585 28.792 42.054C25.647 47.523 23.995 53.723 24 60.031C24.006 66.34 25.669 72.537 28.823 78L8.03805 90Z" fill="url(#paint0_radial)"/>
       
        <defs>
        <radialGradient id="paint0_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(33.75 85.753) rotate(133.887) scale(122.252 128.721)">
        <stop stop-color="#DCDCDC"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#8A8A8A" stop-opacity="0.85"/>
        </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        </svg>
```

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Какую часть? Чем текущий результат отличается от желаемого?

Comment: @andreymal чтоб поверх этого допустим красного цвета был прогрес бар